# How to successfully upgrade Chocolatey

Tags: chocolatey

Attempts to upgrade Chocolatey fails for me:

```
> choco upgrade chocolatay
Chocolatey v0.11.2
Upgrading the following packages:
chocolatay
By upgrading, you accept licenses for the packages.
chocolatay is not installed. Installing...
chocolatay not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
 Source(s): 'https://community.chocolatey.org/api/v2/'
 NOTE: When you specify explicit sources, it overrides default sources.
If the package version is a prerelease and you didn't specify `--pre`,
 the package may not be found.
```

Are there ways out of this predicament?

```
choco upgrade chocolatay -f
```

has much the same result.

Comment: It's **chocolatey** - not "chocolatay" - it has an **e** before the **y** - not an **a** ..... Trying running  `choco upgrade chocolatey`

Comment: @marc_s: <blush> thanks mate. That was silly... But I leave it here in case someone else with butter fingers runs into the same ''problem''

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like it's just a typo - the product is called **Chocolatey** (with an **e** before the **y** - not an "a") - so try this:

```
choco upgrade chocolatey
```

and you should be fine :-)